# Erro ao executar Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Ao abrir o Android Studio, houve uma tela de aviso descrevendo:

> Internal error. Please report to http://code.google.com/p/android/issues
>
> ```
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate registration for EP: Designer.customizations
>         at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionsAreaImpl.registerExtensionPoint(ExtensionsAreaImpl.java:323)
>         at com.intellij.openapi.extensions.impl.ExtensionsAreaImpl.registerExtensionPoint(ExtensionsAreaImpl.java:135)
>         at com.intellij.ide.plugins.IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.registerExtensionPoints(IdeaPluginDescriptorImpl.java:281)
>         at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.registerExtensionPointsAndExtensions(PluginManagerCore.java:1161)
>         at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initializePlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1143)
>         at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManagerCore.initPlugins(PluginManagerCore.java:1179)
>         at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.loadApplicationComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:360)
>         at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.(ApplicationImpl.java:238)
>         at com.intellij.openapi.application.ex.ApplicationManagerEx.createApplication(ApplicationManagerEx.java:45)
>         at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.(IdeaApplication.java:101)
>         at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:41)
>         at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
> ```

Comment: Qual versão do Android Studio você está usando? `0.6.1`? `0.8.1`?

Comment: Olá, esse erro pude corrigir apenas substituindo o programa por completo, não as bibliotecas em Java. a minha versão é Android Studio v0.8.0;

Answer (score 3):

Isto é instalação corrompida, faz o seguinte deleta o bin, lib, license, plugins e o folder no sistema e refaz o procedimento de instalação

Comment: Funciona também.